# Setting background image of a div inside async for loop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, angularfire2

I have an observable array inside my ionic application. I'm looping through the array and try to set the background image like this:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let picture of pictures$ | async;"
   <div class="user-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (picture.image)  + ')'}">
      </div>
</ion-card>
```

Weirdly this isn't setting the image url as the background-image. Because if i inspect the html, i see the following:

```
<div _ngcontent-god-c2="" class="user-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></div>
```

**[object Object]** When i just print the variable out in my html file like this {{picture.image}}, i'll see the image url fine. Which looks something like this: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/someFancyApp-fd93d.appspot.com/o/yadayadayada..
But when i try it to bind this to a ng-style it's saying [object Object]...

I also tried setting the background-image with a pipe, like:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (picture.image | async)  + ')'}"
```

But this didn't work either.

Does someone have any idea why i'm seeing this?

Comment: I created angular-app (not ionic, I got it) and inserted your code. It works. Look at here please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtztap

Comment: Thanks. Although your code looks almost exactly the same as mine it still doesn't work. Unfortunately...

Comment: what doesn't work in alex's code?

Comment: Alex's code works fine. I meant that applying his code to mine didn't work.

Comment: @O.S.Kaya, could you create an ion-app in the stackblitz please?

Comment: That'll take me a long time to do, because my app depends on specific libraries and services, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to wrap your `*ngFor` with an `<ng-container/>` tag, allowing to run the for loop ensuring that the `pictures$ | async` already has resolved

please check my stackblitz here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-aavefm

change the `Observable.of` with the one that fits your needs (guess an API call)

Comment: What is the profit of your approach? @O.S.Kaya made it like yours.

Comment: @mr_alex I wouldn't set directly an `async` pipe over an `*ngFor`, I like it to be separated for a more understandable code, but obviously is just my opinion. I've changed the `background-image` to be directly binded from `style.backgroundImage` instead of `ngStyle` or something like that. Anyway, it actually works